# How to set a Sinon spy for a dependency defined in a class, rather than a Sinon stub?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I am unit testing a method defined in a module, which itself calls a dependency defined in a second module.  I want to set a spy for the method-under-test's call to the dependency, using the Sinon package. How do I do that? I've seen Sinon's page on mocking the dependency of a module ([see here](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/)), and have been able to use it successfully in the past.  But in this case, my test code (see below) is still calling the original method, not the spy.

FYI in my code, if I assign a Sinon *stub* to the method, instead of Sinon *spy*, then the stubbed method is indeed called, as expected. I'm not sure why I can stub, but not spy in this case.

In this case, using `stub` is fine for my purposes.  But I'm curious as to why I cannot use `spy` here as I've done in the past.

Thanks.

---

**My Code**

*combo-test.js (test file)*

```
  const { tape } = require('tape')
  const sinon = require('sinon')
  const { myCombo } = require('./lib/ow/combo')
  const { ComboDropdown } = require('../../../lib/ow/combo-dropdown')

  const comboObject = myCombo(props)// Instantiate object to expose method-under-test.

  sinon.spy(ComboDropdown.prototype, 'extMethod')// Mock call to external method with a spy.
  // sinon.stub(ComboDropdown.prototype, 'extMethod')

  comboObj.myMethod()// Prints to console:  555
```

*combo.js (defines method-under-test)*

```
const { ComboDropdown } = require('./combo-dropdown')

class Combo extends myClass {
  constructor(props) {
  }
  myMethod() {// method-under-test
    this.dropdown = new ComboDropdown({
    })
    this.dropdown.extMethod()//Calls external method.
  }
}
const myCombo = props => new Combo(props)
module.exports = { myCombo }
```

*combo-dropdown.js (defines external method)*

```
class ComboDropdown extends Dropdown {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  extMethod() {
    console.log(555)
  }
}
module.exports = {
  ComboDropdown
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `sinon.spy(object, "method")` creates a spy that wraps the existing function `object.method`. The spy will behave exactly like the original method (including when used as a constructor), but you will have access to data about all `calls`.

`sinon.spy()` just add the [calls](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spy-call/) information to the target method without changing its behavior or implementation, leaving it with its original implementation. With the calls information, you can make assertions after executing the code under test, such as whether the method was called or not.

If you want to have both the calls information and also change the implementation of the target method. `sinon.stub(object, 'method')` is the correct way. It will replace `object.method` with a stub function.

Besides, you can use such `stub.returns(obj);` API to make the stub return the provided value.

Comment: OK gotcha, now everything is clicking, thanks.  Until now, for some reason I was under the impression `sinon.spy()` would add call information *and* replace the mocked function with a noop, i.e. prevent the original function from running at all.  But what you've said makes complete sense.  It's great to be clear on all that now.  Thanks!